# Passing functions to the `events` hash

Tags: backbone.js

Inside `Backbone.View` instances one can set an `events` hash of callbacks:

```
events: { 'click #element' : 'myFunction' }
```

When the function I try to access is not a direct function of the view instance  (e.g. `this.model.myFunction`) I cannot pass the function right in the `events` hash. I have tried:

```
events: { 'click #element' : 'model.myFunction' }
```

and

```
events: { 'click #element' : this.model.myFunction }
```

How can I tell my backbone view to use `this.model.myFunction` as a callback right from the `events` hash?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't do that. The [relevant chunk of Backbone](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/master/backbone.js#L1261) looks like this:

```
delegateEvents : function(events) {
  if (!(events || (events = getValue(this, 'events')))) return;
  this.undelegateEvents();
  for (var key in events) {
    var method = this[events[key]];
    if (!method) throw new Error('Event "' + events[key] + '" does not exist');
    //...
```

So the values in `events` have to be the names of methods in your view object. You could route the events yourself though:

```
events: { 'click #element': 'myFunction' },
// ...
myFunction: function(e) {
    this.model.myFunction(e);
}
```

Comment: Agree with this.  Question for the OP: does it really make sense to have an event handler in the Model?

Comment: @jdigital: I'd agree that an event handler (`myFunction(e)`) in the model is odd but an event handler in the view that just calls a model method (`this.model.myFunction(e.something)`) is reasonable enough if `myFunction` is just doing model-ish things.

Comment: @jdigital: I have the view listening to the `model`'s `destroy` event.  I want to destroy the model for `click .remove` from the view, with event handler `this.model.destroy`.

Comment: @muistooshort: I want to call `this.model.destroy` from the view, which I think is quite natural.

Comment: @Randomblue: No, you can't do that, you'd need a little one-liner in your view that just did `this.model.destroy()`. BTW, that probably falls into the "reasonable enough" part of my earlier comment so it doesn't look like you're doing anything weird.